# jQuery Animate Slide Left

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to slide an image left using jquery animate with the easing plugin and it doesn't seem to want to work.

I have an image with the id=1 and the following javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#center-photo img:first').show();
$('#next').click(function() {
    var active = $('#center-photo img:first');
    //Slider Animation
    $('#1')
    .animate(
    { left: 200 }, {
     duration: 'slow',
     easing: 'easeOutBounce'
    })
   .animate(
    { left: 0 }, {
     duration: 'slow',
     easing: 'easeOutBounce'
    });

});
});
```

## next is the link I click to do the animation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First

[What are valid values for the id attribute in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-is-a-valid-value-for-id-attributes-in-html)
**ID's CANNOT START WITH A DIGIT**
It will screw up validation as well as mess with the way browsers parse your html

Second 
What is the position of your image with the id of 1.

A common problem with element positioning is normally when it is defaulted to static try changing the position to relative or absolute.