# How to apply silde toggle effect from left to right

Tags: jquery, html

Hi iam using ajax post method if i click on sidebar and for the ajax success result iam appending it to the div like this

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "{site_url}publish/my_select_section_form/"+item,
      success:function(data){
            $('.sec-details').hide().html(data).slideDown();
        }
    });
```

it giving me sliding down effect and thats fine but if I want to apply toggle from left to right what can I do,can anyone suggest me

Comment: There is no built in function for this to my knowledge but look into animating the left or right attributes. this should give you the desired effects.

Comment: No @Nomad101 iam not looking for inbuilt,bec I also know that it is not possible through in-built,iam looking for any custome code also

Comment: Maybe this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4287578/jquery-animate-slide-left can help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using jQuery UI sould be quite easy:

http://jsbin.com/ipugec/2/edit

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "{site_url}publish/my_select_section_form/"+item,
   success:function(data){
     // $('.sec-details').hide().html(data).slideDown();
     $('.sec-details').hide().html(data).show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);
   }
});
```

Comment: But I got this Uncaught TypeError: Property '#<Object>' of object #<Object> is not a function

Comment: @Gautam3164 have you included **jQuery UI** AFTER you included your jQuery library?

Comment: @Gautam3164 added an example in my answer

Answer (score 0):

You might want to create custom animation by yourself

CSS

```
.sec-details { position: relative; }
```

JS

```
$(".sec-details").hide().html(data)
$(".sec-details")
    .css({ 'opacity': 0, 'display': 'block', 'left' : '-150'})
    .animate({opacity: 1, left: 0}, 500);
```

Here is a demo http://jsbin.com/ufetit/1/edit